# R: transform a dataframe into a visnetwork

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new user of the "visNetwork" package in R, and I am wondering about a way to transform a long data.frame into a *visnetwork*

I have this kind of dataframe:

```
data<-data.frame(link=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E"),node=c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta","Alpha","Delta","Gamma","Beta","Alpha","Beta"),
       sign=c(1,-1))

   link  node sign
1     A Alpha    1
2     A  Beta   -1
3     B Gamma    1
4     B Delta   -1
5     C Alpha    1
6     C Delta   -1
7     D Gamma    1
8     D  Beta   -1
9     E Alpha    1
10    E  Beta   -1
```

And my goal is to transform it in a "visnetwork" like this one:

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta"),
                label=c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c("Alpha","Beta","Delta","Delta"), to = c("Beta","Gamma","Gamma","Alpha"),
                label=c("A+E","D","B","C"),
                arrows="middle")
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visOptions(nodesIdSelection = TRUE)
```

Any idea how do to that ?

what I have tried so far:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id=c(distinct(data,as.character(node))),
                label=c(distinct(data,as.character(node))))
colnames(nodes)[1]<-"id"
colnames(nodes)[2]<-"label"

edges<-tbl_df(data)  %>% 
  group_by(link) %>% 
  arrange(node) %>%
  summarise(nodes  = paste(node, collapse =","))  %>%
  arrange( nodes) %>% 
  separate(nodes,c("from","to"),sep=",") %>% 
  mutate(label=as.character(link)) %>% 
  mutate(arrows="middle") 

visNetwork(nodes, edges)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need two tables for `visNetwork`, one for nodes and one for links.

Starting with your `data` example, the nodes table can simply be the names of the nodes and I give them ids too.

```
data <- data.frame(link=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E"), node=c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta","Alpha","Delta","Gamma","Beta","Alpha","Beta"), sign=c(1,-1))

nodes.df = data.frame(id = 1:length(unique(data$node)), label = sort(unique(data$node)) )
```

The links is harder as you need to aggregate your `data` table so that each row becomes a link from node A to node B.

Using dplyr with a far from elegant solution:

```
library(dplyr)
temp.links = as.character(unique(data$link))
# Iterate through link names i.e. A, B...
# and generate a data.frame of link name, from here to there
links.df = data.frame(t(sapply(temp.links, function(x) c(x, unlist(select(filter(data, link == x), node))) )))
# set the names
colnames(links.df) = c('label', 'from', 'to')
# default width to 1 to aggregate next
links.df$width = 1
# Aggregate links with the same from and to values by summing width and combining labels
links.df = merge(aggregate( width ~ from + to , links.df , sum), aggregate( label ~ from + to, links.df, function(x) paste0(x, collapse=' + ')))
```

Now we have our `nodes.df` and `links.df` and we are ready to plot

```
visNetwork(nodes.df, links.df) %>% visLayout(randomSeed = 123)
```

Example that resembles the desired:

[image: example]

If your data is very long and the aggregations join a bunch of named links connecting two nodes then the label *A+B+C* will become very long. I personally don't like to label the edges/links with the names rather the width or weight of that edge.